# Combining Steam OpenID 2.0 with Supabase auth

Tags: typescript, authentication, sveltekit, supabase

So I'm currently using the [node-steam-openid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-steam-openid) package in my SvelteKit app in order to allow users to Sign in with Steam. This works fine, and it returns the user's `steam_id` on the server side.

However, Steam is not supported as a Supabase provider. It wouldn't make any sense to have users sign up with email/password, or any of the other options offered.

I'd like to make use of the [SvelteKit auth helper](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/sveltekit) if possible, but I'm not sure how exactly.

I should note that I have RLS enabled, and there are a lot of operations that users should only be able to make on their own rows.

I was thinking I could use the Supabase JWT secret to sign a token with the `jsonwebtoken` package, and then set that in the user's `event.locals` or something. But then I run into the issue of managing refresh tokens. It seems you can also create a Supabase Policy to inspect the JWT, e.g., to check if the `steam_id` in that matches the `steam_id` of the row they're trying to modify.

I noticed that the `supabase.auth.admin.createUser()` function lists `email` and `password` as optional in [the docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-admin-createuser). So perhaps I could just specify the `steam_id` in metadata? But then `supabase.auth.signInWithPassword()` "Requires either an email and password or a phone number and password".

I need to make sure that `auth.users` is linked to my own `public.users` (which uses `steam_id` as a primary key) somehow. When a new user signs in via Steam, they should be added to both tables.

I also want to use the SvelteKit `hooks.server.ts` middleware to inspect user sessions for more complex operations.